# jQuery get VID and MID of each URL and make a link

Tags: jquery

I would like to have a piece of jQuery to get the `VID` and `MID` of each of the links and then write into each of the `EDIT` urls.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="garage_modification.php?mode=view_modification&VID=6&MID=11" class="item">Induction Kit</a> - <a href="garage_vehicle.php?mode=edit_modification" class="edit">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="garage_modification.php?mode=view_modification&VID=6&MID=12"class="item">Induction Kit</a> - <a href="garage_vehicle.php?mode=edit_modification" class="edit">Edit</a></li>
</ul
```

It would essentially look like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="garage_modification.php?mode=view_modification&VID=6&MID=11" class="item">Induction Kit</a> - <a href="garage_vehicle.php?mode=edit_modification&VID=6&MID=11" class="edit">Edit</a></li>
    <li><a href="garage_modification.php?mode=view_modification&VID=6&MID=12"class="item">Induction Kit</a> - <a href="garage_vehicle.php?mode=edit_modification&VID=6&MID=12" class="edit">Edit</a></li>
</ul>
```

The links generated will be dynamic which is why I will want to use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to parse the href and pull out the VID and MID values, then use `.next()` to get the element to append the values to:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zhFJH/)

```
$('.item').each(function(i, val){
    var VID = '', MID = '', param, editAnchor;
    var parts = val.href.substr(val.href.indexOf('?')+1).split('&');
    $.each(parts, function(ind, part){
        param = part.split('=');
        switch(param[0]){
            case 'VID': VID = param[1]; break;
            case 'MID': MID = param[1]; break;
        }
    });
    editAnchor = $(this).next('.edit');
    editAnchor.attr('href', editAnchor.attr('href') + '&VID=' + VID + '&MID=' + MID);
});
```